# Mouse hover event in calendar

Tags: asp.net

I need to show a tool tip on a calendar mouse hover event ,Is there an event for mouse hover in calendar control? Or is there a way to  do this in java script?

Comment: You do not have the Calendar control in ASP classic. Please remove that tag because it is not what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `title="Your tool tip message"` to the html tag on which u wish to display mouse hover.

Eg: Assume the calender is wrapped inside a `div`, then add `<div title="Your message"> calender tags... </div>`